# Multiple XSL to single PDF

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

We have 5 xsl files, the xml content for transformation genertated at runtime, it is working fine when we are generating a single pdf for single xsl file.

Our requirement is we need to generate a single pdf for the 5 xsl files based on runtime input.

ex: the input is 3 xsl file name then we need to genrtate a single pdf containg the 3 xsl contents in multiple pages.

We are using Apache FOP 1.0 and Java 1.5.

Thanks in advance

Thanks
-Arul

Answer (score 0):

As you're already able to convert the XSL to PDF, you may try to [concatenate multiple PDF files](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-java/concatenate-pdf-documents.html), created from those XSL files, into a single PDF using [Aspose.Pdf.Kit for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-java/default.aspx).
The code is very simple:

```
//read the input file
String inFile1 = "example1.pdf";
String inFile2 = "example2.pdf";
String outFile = "kitOut1.pdf";

FileInputStream inStream1 = new FileInputStream(inFile1);
FileInputStream inStream2 = new FileInputStream(inFile2);


//concatenate two files
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
PdfFileEditor editor = new PdfFileEditor();
editor.concatenate(inStream1, inStream2, outputStream);

//close the output FileOutputStream
outputStream.close();
```

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.